# How can I use generics to put this method in the parent class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a number of **plural item** classes which each have a collection of **singular item** classes, like this:

```
public class Contracts : Items
{
        public List<Contract> _collection = new List<Contract>();
        public List<Contract> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection;
            }
        }
}

public class Customers: Items
{
        public List<Customer> _collection = new List<Customer>();
        public List<Customer> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection;
            }
        }
}

public class Employees: Items
{
        public List<Employee> _collection = new List<Employee>();
        public List<Employee> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection;
            }
        }
}
```

I can imagine I could use generics to **put this up into the parent class**. How could I do this, I imagine it would look something like this:

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
public class Items
{
        public List<T> _collection = new List<T>();
        public List<T> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's completely right, except you also want a `<T>` after Items:

```
public class Items<T>
{
        public List<T> _collection = new List<T>();
        public List<T> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection;
            }
        }
}
```

To instantiate:

```
Items<Contract> contractItems = new Items<Contract>();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, although Items would have to be generic as well.

```
public class Items<TItem>
{
    private IList<TItem> _items = new List<TItem>();
    public IList<TItem> Collection
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
    // ...
 }
```

It would probably make sense to have Items inherit from `IEnumerable<TItem>` too.

Comment: What would that get me if Items inherited from IEnumerable, could I somehow just use Items in a foreach loop? I was looking for a way to do that.

Comment: Yes, you would be able to do foreach (strictly you only need to have a GetEnumerator but you might as well properly implement IEnumerable<TItem>).